# Did I misinterpret this pseudocode?

Tags: c++, arrays, insert

I'm working on an assignment and the professor doesn't want us using any other code to insert values other than his provided pseudocode.

A brief explanation of what I'm doing. I'm creating a dynamic array of integers and they are to be inserted in order (from lowest to highest).

Here is the pseudocode he provided:

> ```
> for (i = valueNum - 1; array[i] is the wrong spot for newValue; --i)  
>     array[i] = array[i-1]
> ```
>
> where array[i] is the wrong spot for newValue:
>
> ```
> (i > 0) AND (value at array[i-1] is greater than newValue)
> ```

He also included this information:

> You should also convince yourself that the above pseudocode is applicable to (i.e., it also covers) the case where the new value to be stored is the #1 value, the case where the new value to be stored is greater than or equal to the highest existing value, and the case where the new value to be stored is less than or equal to the lowest existing value.

So, it seems pretty straight forward. I gave it a try:

```
void IntArray::insert(int nInt)
{
    /* check if resize is needed */
    if(mySize == capacity)
    {
        int newCapacity = capacity * 1.5;
        if(newCapacity == capacity)
            newCapacity = capacity + 1;
        capacity = newCapacity;
    }

    /* here is where my mistake was */ 
    int i;
    mySize++;

    for(i = mySize -1; i > 0 && data[i-1] > nInt; --i)
    {
        data[i] = data[i - 1];
    }
    data[i] = nInt;
}
```

It seems like it correctly follows the pseudocode, but it doesn't seem like it would ever work if `mySize` is either 0 or 1. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried running it with mySize at 0 or 1? What happens?

Comment: Just changing `capacity` without changing the storage isn't going to help very much, is it?  Don't you need to allocate something?  You also never actually store the new value.

Comment: @DamienBlack It simply doesn't enter the loop because it doesn't meet the conditional statement.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, apologies. I forgot to increment the size. Edited the code, but now it enters garbage into the array. I see what you mean (not actually storing the new value). Personally I'm confused as to why we need to use this algorithm, I felt my way of doing it had a much better readability. Should I be inserting the `nInt` at the end and then let that for loop handle the order?

Comment: The update (timed 2014-02-10 19:19:10Z) looks like what I'd expect to use. It clearly works when `mySize` is initially 0; you increment it to 1, then count down (a no-op) setting `data[0] = nInt;`.  When you have one row in place, the new one can be bigger or smaller. If it is bigger, i is not decremented so the new entry goes in `data[1]` where you want it. If it is smaller, `i` is decremented and the old value moved up by the body of the loop, and the new value is inserted in `data[0]` where you want it.  Rinse and repeat...

Comment: I managed to get it working. When I finally figure it out, I find myself wondering what took me so long to get it to work. If you'd like to post any of your comments as a reply, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: The 'puzzled that it took so long' state of mind is normal…well, it is one I frequently find myself in, shall we say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In various comments, I said:

> Just changing capacity without changing the storage isn't going to help very much, is it? Don't you need to allocate something? You also never actually store the new value.

and (mildly edited):

> The update (timed 2014-02-10 19:19:10Z) looks like what I'd expect to use. It clearly works when `mySize` is initially 0; you increment it to 1, then set `i = 0` and count down (a no-op), ending up setting `data[0] = nInt;`. When you have one row in place, the new one can be bigger than the existing one, or smaller than or equal to the existing one. If it is bigger, `i` is not decremented so the new entry goes in `data[1]` where you want it. If it is smaller, `i` is decremented and the old value moved up by the body of the loop, and the new value is inserted in `data[0]` where you want it. Rinse and repeat…